# AWS EB deployment - where is my app?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I packaged my Scala/LiftWeb app with the sbt one-jar plugin into a single executable jar file and packed it up with Docker, exposing the embedded Jetty's port in the Dockerfile.

It runs fine locally on Docker and appearently deploys clean on AWS EB using the CLI deployment tools. On the received EB URL however, all I see is the congrats page saying "Your Docker Container is now running in Elastic Beanstalk on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud.".

So, where is my app? Do I miss any steps making my app publicly available on my EB instance?

Comment: Whats the result of "eb create --verbose"?

Comment: "Invalid command: create." - I have aws-eb-cli version 2.6.3-2 coming from Archlinux's AUR (user maintained packages). Shall I try to upgrade my CLI package manually?

Comment: Ah, I see. You must be using the older 2.x version. What's your file structure look like?

Comment: I updated my eb-cli version to the latest 3.x and now the error is obvious - building the Docker image on AWS failed because it tried to add my local jar file to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the problem was caused by using an obsolete 2.x version of the aws-eb-cli tools package. Upgrading it to 3.x made the error obvious - building the docker image has failed on AWS.

What I was looking for was running an existing docker image, I found instruction for this scenario at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-docker/.

Thanks a lot for Nick for asking the right questions which made me realize the obsolete tools package!